# Clojurescript, how to access a map within a indexed sequence

Tags: data-structures, clojure, sequence, clojurescript, seq

`(println (get-in @app-state ["my-seq"]))`

Returns the following sequence with type `cljs.core/IndexedSeq`

```
([-Jg95JpA3_N3ejztiBBM {create_date 1421803605375, 
  website "www.example.com", first_name "one"}]
 [-Jg95LjI7YWiWE233eK1 {create_date 1421803613191, 
  website "www.example.com", first_name "two"}] 
 [-Jg95MwOBXxOuHyMJDlI {create_date 1421803618124,     
  website "www.example.com", first_name "three"}])
```

How can I access the maps in the sequence by uid? For example, the map belonging to
 `-Jg95LjI7YWiWE233eK1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the order of the data, you have the following possibilities:

1. Store the data once in order and once as a map. So, when adding a new entry, do something like:

   ```
   (defn add-entry
     [uid data]
     (swap! app-state update-in ["my-seq"]
            #(-> %
                 (update-in [:sorted] conj data)
                 (update-in [:by-uid] assoc uid data))))
   ```

   With lookup functions being:

   ```
   (defn sorted-entries
     []
     (get-in @app-state ["my-seq" :sorted]))

   (defn entry-by-uid
     [uid]
     (get-in @app-state ["my-seq" :by-uid uid]))
   ```

   This has the best lookup performance but will use more memory and make the code a little bit more complex.
2. Search the entry in the seq:

   ```
   (defn entry-by-uid
     [uid]
     (->> (get @app-state "my-seq")
          (filter (comp #{uid} first))
          (first)))
   ```

   In the worst case, this has to traverse the whole seq to find your entry.

If order does not matter, I recommend storing the data as a map in the first place:

```
(defn add-entry
  [uid data]
  (swap! app-state assoc-in ["my-seq" uid] data))

(defn entry-by-uid
  [uid]
  (get-in @app-state ["my-seq" uid]))
```

Comment: I had a map, and did a `(sort-by last {map})` which returned an `cljs.core/IndexedSeq` I'm trying `(get-in @app-state ["my-seq" :by-uid uid])` but it's returning nil.

Comment: My second suggestion should work then - basically: `(first (filter (comp #{uid} first) (get @app-state "my-seq")))`. But I recommend that you store your data according to its use, e.g. if you need lookup by UID store it as a map, but if you need to access it in-order use a seq. If you need both, use both representations (which was the first suggestion in my answer).